# Поменять местами столбцы с минимальной и максимальной суммой элементов

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Задание:

"Вывести исходную матрицу N на M, в которой столбцы с минимальной и максимальной суммой элементов поменяны местами. Числа разделять пробелами. Если присутствует несколько столбцов с одинаковой минимальной суммой элементов, то использовать первый по порядку. Аналогично с максимальной суммой. "

Мой вопрос:

Для примера:

Sample Input:

3 4

1 2 3 4

1 3 4 5

0 2 3 -2

Sample Output:

3 2 1 4

4 3 1 5

3 2 0 -2

Буду признателен за помощь!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, m ;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int arr[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
    }

    int max = 0, min = 0;

    int min_index = 0, max_index = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum += arr[i][j];
        max = sum > max ? sum : max;
        max_index = max == sum ? j : max_index;

        min = sum < min ? sum : min;
        min_index = min == sum ? j : min_index;


    }



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int temp = arr[i][min_index];
        arr[i][min_index] = arr[i][max_index];
        arr[i][max_index] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Сам решил. Может кому-то будет нужно.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, m ;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);
    int arr[n][m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
    }

    int max = -9999, min = 9999;

    int min_index = 9999, max_index = -9999;

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            sum += arr[i][j];
        max = sum > max ? sum : max;
        max_index = max == sum ? j : max_index;

        min = sum < min ? sum : min;
        min_index = min == sum ? j : min_index;


    }



    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int temp = arr[i][min_index];
        arr[i][min_index] = arr[i][max_index];
        arr[i][max_index] = temp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max_index = max == sum ? j : max_index;` вот здесь вы меняете индекс вне зависимости от того когда был посчитан `max` равный `sum`, на предыдущей итерации (тогда индекс менять не надо) или на текущей. Вы можете добавить дополнительный флаг, сигнализирующий о том, что `max` (с `min` аналогично) был присвоен на текущей итерации, и в случае, если он равен `true`, менять номер индекса.

Comment: Благодарю за участие, бро!